# Getting CSC : error CS0009: Metadata file 'C:\Y.dll' could not be opened -- Image is too small when using remote signed from jenkins pipeline

Tags: security, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dotnet-build

I have two project X.csproj and Y.csproj and X is referring Y.
Now If I build X.csproj using following command from Jenkins pipeline,

```
powershell "dotnet build ./X.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:ApiKey=${env.SignApiKey} -p:RemoteSignEnabled=true /p:Platform=x64"
```

Build is failing with following error,

Build FAILED.

CSC : error CS0009: Metadata file 'C:\Y\bin\x64\Release\net472\Y.dll' could not be opened -- Image is too small. [C:\X.csproj]
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

However If I run the build with p:RemoteSignEnabled=false,it is working.
It also works locally. Please help me resolving  the issue.